# Javascript - Problems with decimal point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a script (I am a rookie level 0), and it turns out that I am trying to show a **hidden div** (#regalo) when the result of a sum is **> xxx**, but problem is that it only works with integers values, and not with decimals...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- jQuery 2.2.4 -->

<style>
    .tooltip {
        display: none;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background: red
    }
</style>

<div id="regalo">1</div>

<div id="ver-carrito">
  <p>Products in your cart:</p>
  <div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>
  <div id="cont-resultado">
    <p>Total to pay:</p>

    <input name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- **** ID TOTAL **** -->

  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-1">
    Product 1<br><br>499 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="499" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="499.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-2">
    Product 2<br><br>299 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="299" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="299.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-3">
    Product 3<br><br>399 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="399" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="399.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note the value = "499"** ... This value (without decimal) works well.

But if the value = "**499.99**" my script doesn't work anymore, and it doesn't show the hidden div.

> **NOTE:** I think that here I only have a problem with decimals. The rest of the script works great without them.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function manageRegalo() {

    var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
    //var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
    var total = Number($("#total"));
    if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
      total = totalStorage;
    }

    //if(total > 999.99 && total < 2999.99) { This it does not work for me.

    if (total > 999 && total < 2999) { //This works perfectly. Without decimals

      $('#regalo').show();
      if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
        $('.tooltip').show();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 9000);

        localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
      } // New - Local Storage for Tooltip
    } else {
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();

      //localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
      localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total")));
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

Comment: You replace `.` with `''` when assigning to `total`. You will find, however, that JavaScript has issues with Floating Point Math. You may want to also consider that if you're doing Math.

Comment: I agree, I think get rid of the `.val().replace(".",""));` and this probably will work

Comment: @StackSlave ... I am not doing math. It is a prototype online store. The problem is that, speaking of product prices, in Europe we use values ​​such as *499,99* (with a comma), and in my practice I can't put them in the html ( `value = "499,99"`), since the script does work well, but does not show the hidden div (with a point or comma, ignores it). I can't find how to solve this, really...

Comment: @Dr_Derp ... I deleted it ( `var total = Number($("#total"));` ), but it still doesn't work. The script ignores the decimal points in the html ( `value = "499.99"` ) and the hidden div still doesn't show. If I delete the comma (*value = "499"*), yes, then it does work...

Comment: Where is `total` coming from? Have you made sure that you are getting the expected value? (between the bounds of your `if` and no weird string conversion)

Comment: @msg ... The original script is too large to publish here, so I only published the fragment that makes a div visible ( `#regalo` ) when the indicated value `if (total> 999 && total <2999)` is calculated. Example, 3 clicks on the div (html) with input `value="499"` when adding them (499 + 499 + 499) does arrive and exceeds the minimum value ( `total>999` ) and then shows the hidden div, but a input with decimal (`"499.99"`), it no longer shows the hidden div `#regalo` (gift). I really can't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some `console.log` and make sure that is always doing numeric addition and not string concatenation?

Comment: @msg ... The console does not show the slightest error. I still don't find the problem. I edited the post for a better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Help me @Bibberty , please! ... :)

Comment: `$("#total")` gets the object not the value, I get `NaN` (not a number) when using `Number`. User need `$("#total").val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you are comparing like with like. Instead of using `Number()` use `parseFloat($("#total").val())` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function manageRegalo() {

    //var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
    //var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
    var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());
    
    /*if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
      total = totalStorage;
    }*/

    if(total > 999.99 && total < 2999.99) { //This it does not work for me.
      console.log("PASS");
    //if (total > 999 && total < 2999) { //This works perfectly. Without decimals

      $('#regalo').show();
      if (/*localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null*/true) {
        $('.tooltip').show();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 9000);

        //localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
      } // New - Local Storage for Tooltip
    } else {
      console.log("FAIL");
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();

      //localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
      //localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total")));
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ver-carrito">
  <p>Products in your cart:</p>
  <div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>
  <div id="cont-resultado">
    <p>Total to pay:</p>

    <input name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly" value="1000">
    <!-- **** ID TOTAL **** -->

  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-1">
    Product 1<br><br>499 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="499" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="499.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-2">
    Product 2<br><br>299 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="299" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="299.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-3">
    Product 3<br><br>399 €
    <input class="add-prod" value="399" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- value="399.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jon P ... Your proposal sounds good. I have tried the changes and now the hidden div is shown (with the values with decimals (great!)), **but I have lost the localStorage function** that you have commented on in the script. I have uncommented this, but I can't retrieve the localStorage for the tooltip. (I have cleared my cache, of course). How do I recover the lost function ...? I hope your comments. Thanks...

Comment: Only reason I commented out the `localStorage`  lines were they cause erros in the StackSnippet sandbox (Stack Overflow's interactive code section). Restoring those work. Make sure to restore all of them,

Comment: Hi @Jon P ... It is right. I had not observed the detail of the snippet. I edited his script to adapt it to my development and it works very well. It is a clean and tidy solution. +10! ... Thanks. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I guess I have fixed the issue for you.

Please have a look and let me know.

```js
var total = 0;
var totalStorage = 0;
function manageRegalo(clicked_value) {
 total = +$("#total").val() + +clicked_value;
 $("#total").val(total);
 /*localStorage.setItem('total', total);
 var totalStorage = localStorage.getItem("total");
 if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
  total = totalStorage;
 }*/
  doThings();
}

function doThings() {

 if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { 
  
    $('#regalo').show();
    /*if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
      $('.tooltip').show();

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
      },9000);

      if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //play audio
        $("#notify")[0].pause(); //play audio
        $("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //play audio
      } else { // play audio
        setTimeout(function() { //play audio
          $("#notify")[0].play(); //play audio
        });
      } //play audio

      localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true');
    }*/ // New - Local Storage for Tooltip
  } else{
   $('#regalo').hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 manageRegalo(0);


  $(document).on('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.add-prod')) {
      manageRegalo(event.target.value);
    
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.tooltip { display:none;width:60px;height:60px;background:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regalo">1</div>


<div id="ver-carrito">  
<p>Productos en tu Carrito:</p>
<div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>
<div id="cont-resultado"><p>Total a pagar:</p>

<input name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly" value="0"> <!-- **** ID TOTAL **** -->

</div>
</div>



<div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-1">
  Product 1<br><br>499 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="499.99" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="499.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-2">
  Product 2<br><br>299 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="299.99" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="299.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-3">
  Product 3<br><br>399 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="399.99" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="399.99" The script does not work -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your comment could be greatly improved by explaining what you have done. It is often hard to spot one line changes in a large chunk of code.